# space key,page down and end not working

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth 3.0 keyboard and the space key,page down and end doesn't work. I think I pressed alt options .All the other keys are working beside these 3 keys.Can someone please help me

Comment: What kind of Mac?  What brand of keyboard?

Comment: I know this is already closed as a duplicate, but is this actually an Apple question?